# Updating a picklist value label in managed package field - deploy necessary?

Tags: managed-package, picklist

If I update the picklist value labels for one of the fields in my managed package, will I need to deploy that change to subscriber orgs for it to be picked up? Or will it automatically be picked up?

Comment: Picklists do not update when you install a managed package upgrade because these are subscriber editable. You will need to update it separately on each subscriber org. It would be possible to automate using metadata API or tooling API, most easily from a dev ops tool or an IDE. It would be hard to do from Apex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm) documentation, by the fact that the [Custom Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_custom_field) section doesn't list editing the picklist values, is incomplete.

However, packaged picklist values **do not update** when you install a managed package upgrade containing changes to the picklist values because these are subscriber editable.

You will need to explicitly update the picklist field's values separately on each subscriber org. It is possible to automate this using the metadata or tooling APIs, most easily done using sfdx CLI, a dev ops tool or an IDE. It would be hard to do from Apex.

As noted by @DavidReed in comments, such deployments can cause loss of subscriber-created values (or at least deactivation of them).

NB: Picklists in [Custom Metadata Type fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_custom_field_CMT) behave differently and can be updated. New values are always added to the subscriber org on upgrade, but you cannot delete existing values. In addition, be warned that adding a picklist value to a previously released CMT field is irreversible - and in the 1GP scenario simply adding the value on the packaging org locks that value in place even without creating any package versions.

Comment: +1; also note that deploying a picklist value set is destructive and can overwrite any subscriber modifications.